# How to Update a GridView when boundfield is used

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a `GridView` and it is bound to a database. I am finding difficulties in updating the `GridView`  and corresponding table in the database.

My asp code for `GridView` after binding to SQLdatasource is :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing"
    OnRowUpdating="GridView2_RowUpdating" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView2_RowCancelingEdit"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataKeyNames="Locations">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Locations" HeaderText="Locations" 
            SortExpression="Locations" ReadOnly="true"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Lamp_pro4" HeaderText="Lamp_pro4" 
            SortExpression="Lamp_pro4" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Lamp_pro5" HeaderText="Lamp_pro5" 
            SortExpression="Lamp_pro5" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AC_Profile5" HeaderText="AC_Profile5" 
            SortExpression="AC_Profile5" />
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TouchPadConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Quantity]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

My datakey is Locations and its readonly.

The .cs code for updating is:

```
protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ARCHANA-PC\\ARCHANA;Initial Catalog=TouchPad;Integrated Security=True");
        string LocName = GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["Locations"].ToString();
        TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Lamp_pro4");
        TextBox txt2 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Lamp_pro5");
        TextBox txt3 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("AC_Profile5");
        string updStmt = "UPDATE Quantity set Lamp_pro4=@Lamp_pro4,Lamp_pro5=@Lamp_pro5,AC_Profile5=@AC_Profile5 where Locations=@locName";

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand updCmd = new SqlCommand(updStmt, con);

        updCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locName", LocName);
        updCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lamp_pro4", txt1.Text);
        updCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lamp_pro5", txt2.Text);
        updCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AC_Profile5", txt3.Text);
        updCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        GridView2.DataBind();

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You must call `GridView2.DataBind()` in the end of your treatment

```
protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    //GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    string LocName = GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["Locations"].ToString();
    TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Lamp_pro4");
    TextBox txt2 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Lamp_pro5");
    TextBox txt3 = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("AC_Profile5");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Quantity set Lamp_pro4='" + txt1.Text + "',Lamp_pro5='" + txt2.Text + "',AC_Profile5='" + txt3.Text + "' where Locations=" + LocName, con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
    //BindQuantity();
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

2) Define `UpdateCommand` on your `SqlDataSource`

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TouchPadConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Quantity]"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE Quantity set Lamp_pro4 = @Lamp_pro4 ,Lamp_pro5=@Lamp_pro5,AC_Profile5=@AC_Profile5 where Locations=@Locations">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updatecommand.aspx

Comment: Nope its not working. Error at the Update command: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: whant the line on this exception is thrown ?

Comment: Yes you must define UpdateCommand Archana i send you link very interessant

Comment: I also tried UpdateCommand on sqldatasorce, yet not working. I wonder should I add templatefield,Itemtemplate and edittemplate in the asp code...But I dunno how to add. kindly help by editing my code.

Comment: I'am happy to help you Archana

Answer (score 1):

Just call `GridView2.DataBind()` to rebind your data onto the control.

Anyway you should really use **SQL Parameters** to prevent SQL Injection! Have a look at this example

```
string connetionString = "YOUR_CONSTR" ;
string updStmt = "UPDATE Quantity set Lamp_pro4=@lamp_pro4,Lamp_pro5=@Lamp_pro5,AC_Profile5=@ac_profile5 " + 
                 "where Locations=@locName";

using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
{
  cnn.Open();
  SqlCommand updCmd = new SqlCommand(updStmt , cnn);

  // use sqlParameters to prevent sql injection!
  updCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lamp_pro4", txt1.Text);

  // or define dataType if necessary
  SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter();
  p1.ParameterName = "@Lamp_pro5";
  p1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
  p1.Value = txt2.Text;
  updCmd.Parameters.Add(p1);

  // demo code must be adapted!! (correct paramNames, textbox names, add missing params ...)

  int affectedRows = updCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  Debug.WriteLine(affectedRows + " rows updated!");
}
```

If you have problems accessing your textboxes you may adapt this example

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string Lamp_pro4 = e.NewValues["Lamp_pro4"].ToString();
    Debug.WriteLine("Lamp_pro4: " + Lamp_pro4); // to check if everything works fine!
}
```

Comment: No its not working. And yeah I will implement it with SQL Parameters once this gets goin.

Comment: Nope its not working. Error at the Update command: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I have edited my question based on what you have sent.

Comment: I don't see any instance of SqlConnection created!? Something like SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CON_STR) or perhaps a using like in my example. Furthermore there is no executeNonQuery() and gridView2.DataBind()

Comment: I have edited my code in the question with the change what you asked me to do. Yest not working. When I debug the program : the txt1,txt2,txt3 is null. I think it is not holding the value that i entered in the Grid. Some small mistake. Cant figure out what it is. Kindly help.

Comment: I wrote a small example code to show how you can easily access your new values within your gridView!

Answer (score 0):

Working with a data bound grid view and bound columns required no code behind.  The ASPX markup does all the updates for you.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="recid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="recid" HeaderText="recid" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="recid" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BranchName" HeaderText="BranchName" SortExpression="BranchName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ParentId" HeaderText="ParentId" SortExpression="ParentId" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ZA_testConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Branch]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [BRANCH] SET BranchName=@BranchName , ParentId=@ParentId WHERE recid=@recid">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have tested this code, and it reads the table, and allows the edits of the records.  Points to warch for.  Make sure you have an update query. Make sure the parameters on the update match the field names (@branchName, @ParentId). On the gridview control select Enable editing.

Comment: Giving me an error in the browser: Must declare the scalar variable "@Locations". If I remove InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True", its working but all the other rows rows are getting edited with the same values. Help me please, while am in the urge of getting rid of this issue. Thank you

Comment: Your column headings or SQL field names will automatically be declared as variables. If there is a column in your select data [Locations] , you can use set [Locations]=@locations in your insert statement. Hope this helps.