# Asp Gridview use Boundfields? or Templatefields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, templatefield, boundfield

I put data in a data table e.g.

```
dt.TableName = "SA1";
da.Fill(dt);

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Now I'm not sure if I should use boundfield (For all columns)

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Unit" HeaderText="Unit" SortExpression="Unit"  />
```

or use

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        Units
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbUnits" Text='<%# Eval("Unit")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and add the data as i go along, the gridview's purpose is only to display data

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to display rows without anything fancy, or any particular design, you would use **BoundField**. However if you would like to design the displaying of the record in a different manner than the default - you would need to create your own row template, by using the **TemplateField**.

Check out these links - they briefly explain the differences, but it is basically default VS customised presentation.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1369418.aspx?boundfield+vs+template+field+in+gridview
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Interviews/answer/1751/difference-between-boundfield-and-templatefield

Comment: I want to use BoundField for some reason, but Can I will be able to Edit things when I needed with boundField ?

Comment: Yes you can. You can find an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221055/how-to-update-a-gridview-when-boundfield-is-used

Answer (score 4):

If you want to just display the data then you should use bound field attribute.

Answer (score 1):

- The BoundField displays the value of specified DataSource field as
  text.
- The TemplateField allows for a mix of HTML markup, Web    controls,
  and data-binding syntax.

  Your purpose is only to display data.So i think you need BoundField Here